# Adaptar código para generar ComboBox dinámicos

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola a todos soy yo de nuevo molestando :), tengo un código que genera inputs dinamicamente, y los puedo devolver en un php en forma de array, **este código no es mio lo encontré en una pagina** pero no tiene una explicación amplia así que tengo dudas en como podría adaptarlo para que aparte del input me imprima un ComboBox que trae información de la base de datos.
Este es el HTML y el script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="number" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
            }
        });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Container">
        <form action="GuardarIngredientes.php" role="form" method="post">
            <div class="field_wrapper">
                <div>
                    <input type="number" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="btn-guardar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
        </form>
     </div>
</body>
```

Posteriormente el formulario lo mando a un archivo php con el siguiente codigo

```
<?php
print '<pre>';
print_r($_REQUEST['field_name']);
print '</pre>';
//output

// Get multiple input field's value 
$field_values_array = $_POST['field_name'];

foreach($field_values_array as $value){
    // Your database query goes here
}
?>
```

y se ve algo así, si introduzco datos en los inputs.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este código ya lo modifique un poco agregando el ComboBox al input inicial pero hasta ahí llegue.

```
  <?php
        require_once("Insumo.php");
        $insumo = new Insumo(); 
        $listaInsumo=$insumo->mostrarTodos();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="number" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'
        ; //New input field html 
        var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
        $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                x++; //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
                }
            });
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
            x--; //Decrement field counter
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="Container">
            <form action="GuardarIngredientes.php" role="form" method="post">
                <div class="field_wrapper">
                    <div>
                        <input type="number" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
                            <select class="" name="txtIng" id="txtIng" data-width='100%' >
                                        <?php
                                            foreach($listaInsumo as $listi){

                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $listi->idInsumo; ?>"><?php echo $listi->NomInsumo; ?></option>

                                        <?php }?>
                            </select>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="btn-guardar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
            </form>
         </div>
    </body>
```

no se como hacer que el Js lo copie o lo agregue de nuevo como lo hace con el input, si alguien me da una idea o me explica mas a detalle el script y el archivo php seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: quieres generarlo con php ?

Comment: quiero generarlo con Js pero no se si sea posible ya que el ComboBox lo lleno con php

Comment: quieres copiarlo exactamente =?

Comment: si, ya que este formulario es para poder agregar ingredientes a una receta, por ende necesito imprimir el ComboBox "x" veces para ir agregando insumos a esta.

Comment: pero el comboBox varian sus opciones ?

Comment: no, siempre son las mismas opciones ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con jQuery lo puedes capturar asi:

```
var comboBox = $("#txtIng").html();
```

llamas el objeto por el `id` y luego obtines su contenido con `html()`

sin jQuery seria asi:

```
var comboBox = document.getElementById("txtIng").innerText;
```

espero te sirva y la marques... XD

Comment: Por suerte encontré un vídeo tutorial donde hacen unas inserciones múltiples como lo que intento hacer , pero tu respuesta igual es una solución a lo que quería hacer con los ComboBox uwu gj.

Comment: Bueno bro, siempre es un placer ayudar...